# About Print a4 size using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to print a page as A4 size. I use these code but it has a problem, it show different size in different resolution device. I want to print my page as a4 size using all device. I need solution for responsive a4 size print

```
<div class="page">hmmm<div>
 <style>
.page {
    height:1600px;
}

@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}
@media print {
    html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;        
    }
    .page {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
     }
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: `it show different size in different regulation device` can you provide some examples of the sizes in these "regulation" devices (whatever they are)

Comment: sorry for mistake, it is resolution

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `size` descriptor is currently in working draft status and isn't, so far as I can tell, implemented in any browsers.

Head on over to Mozilla.org and see the browser compatibility at the bottom. As of July 2019 it says it's not supported in any major browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

Comment: with great difficulty I would imagine @TaslimaAkhter